# psql breaks if I specify host localhost

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.3, tcpip

I am aware that this or similar has been [asked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20080633/what-value-to-set-in-postgresql-conf-to-enable-use-of-localhost-and-127-0-0-1) [in](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14225038/postgresql-adapter-pg-could-not-connect-to-server) other places. None of the other answers have worked for me.

Machine is a Macbook Pro 2014 / OS X Yosemite 10.10 with Postgres 9.3.5 installed via Homebrew.

I can only connect to my local postgres instance if I do NOT specify a host. This works:

```
psql -Umyuser -d mydb
sql (9.4.4)
Type "help" for help.

myuser=#
```

`-h localhost` does not:

```
psql -Umyuser -d mydb -h localhost
psql: server closed the connection unexpectedly
    This probably means the server terminated abnormally
    before or while processing the request.
```

It pauses for a long time before I get this message.

I am trying to set up a third party tool that seems to want to specify localhost, so it is not an option just to leave that off.

If I understand what I've read correctly elsewhere, postgres behaves differently if you're using TCP/IP, and specifying `-h localhost` forces that. Accordingly I have added  the following in `pg_hba.conf`:

```
local   all             all                                     trust
# IPv4 local connections:
host    all             all             127.0.0.1/32            trust
host    all             all             localhost               trust
# IPv6 local connections:
host    all             all             ::1/128                 trust
```

(127.0.0.1 AND localhost seems redundant but desperation drives superstition) ... and in `postgresql.conf`:

```
listen_addresses = 'localhost'          
port = 5432
```

`netstat` confirms that Postgres is listening to that port:

```
☁  ~  netstat -an | grep 5432
tcp4       0      0  127.0.0.1.5432         *.*                    LISTEN     
tcp6       0      0  ::1.5432               *.*                    LISTEN     
d8d7c0e31d5add1d stream 0 0 d8d7c0e326b18a1d 0 0 0 /tmp/.s.PGSQL.5432
```

All permissions are set on the socket file:

```
~ ls -l /tmp/.s.PGSQL.5432
srwxrwxrwx  1 fritz  wheel  0 12 Jul 13:27 /tmp/.s.PGSQL.5432
```

`/etc/hosts` has an entry for localhost:

```
127.0.0.1   localhost
::1         localhost
```

`psql` and `pg_ctl` are pointing to the same installations:

```
~ which psql               
/usr/local/bin/psql
~ ll /usr/local/bin/psql
/usr/local/bin/psql -> ../Cellar/postgresql/9.4.4/bin/psql
~ which pg_ctl
/usr/local/bin/pg_ctl
~  ll /usr/local/bin/pg_ctl
/usr/local/bin/pg_ctl -> ../Cellar/postgresql/9.4.4/bin/pg_ctl
```

There's nothing named `psql` elsewhere on my system that seems like it could be hijacking this process:

```
~  sudo find / -name psql
/Applications/pgAdmin3.app/Contents/SharedSupport/psql
/Users/fritz/devtools/phantomjs/src/qt/config.tests/unix/psql
/Users/fritz/Qt/5.3/Src/qtbase/config.tests/unix/psql
/Users/fritz/Qt/5.3/Src/qtbase/src/plugins/sqldrivers/psql
/Users/fritz/Qt/5.3/Src/qtbase/src/sql/drivers/psql
/usr/local/bin/psql
/usr/local/Cellar/postgresql/9.4.4/bin/psql
```

UPDATE: telnet connects to localhost 5432 for a while and then is disconnected:

```
~  telnet localhost 5432
Trying ::1...
Connected to localhost.
Escape character is '^]'.
Connection closed by foreign host.
```

UPDATE 2: I used wireshark to spy on tcp localhost port 5432. Trouble is, I don't know what I should see and whether/how the results are wrong. Hoping someone out there can make [something of this capture file](http://www.filedropper.com/psqllocalhostconnection).

Comment: Try `-h 127.0.0.1`. The entry mentioned in `/etc/hosts` is probably not the only IP assigned to `localhost`.

Comment: Tried that, same result.

Comment: Then `telnet 127.0.0.1 5432` in the hope of getting a more meaningful error message.

Comment: Connects and then is closed by the other end. Output added at the end of the question.

Comment: That's a *very* weird issue. `psql` doesn't just exit silently like that. If the connection is closed unexpectedly by the other end it'll print a message when you try the next query, not just exit. Similarly on authentication failures. I have a hard time guessing what might be going on here. In your position I'd be attaching a debugger, and/or doing network traffic capture, to figure out what's going on.

Comment: Maybe there is a packet filter closing connections. Mac OS has [pf](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PF_%28firewall%29). Note in any case that based on the **`Trying ::1`** telnet output above, `localhost` does not resolve to `127.0.0.1` but to `::1` (IPv6).

Comment: Added wireshark packet sniffing results, hope they mean more to someone else.

Comment: @sivann None of these commands work, I don't think they're a part of Mac OS. I didn't have any luck googling e.g. "setenforce mac os equivalent" either.

Comment: @DanielVérité I ran `sudo pfctl -d` to disable pf, still the same problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to the [suggestion on pgsql-general that I check TCP/IP with netcat](http://www.postgresql.org/message-id/5d2441947dbe1deb0d07b43ad548f2f0@smtp.hushmail.com) I discovered that the first few bytes sent to localhost were being swallowed by a process that was intended to keep an audit trail of Internet access. Uninstalled and everything works as I expect.

Answer (score 0):

There seems to be a special case in the PostgreSQL client libraries for `localhost` and `127.0.0.1`. Instead of trying to hit the TCP port, it looks for the UNIX domain socket instead.

I was able to work around this by specifying `localhost.` as the hostname. (I was also able to get the IPv6 `::1` address to work.)